# Root directory only showing about half of total available drive space

Tags: partitioning

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 server edition on an Intel NUC7CJYH, and noticed I only had about 50% of my SSD available. Running `sudo lsblk` showed the following:

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 464.3G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   200G  0 lvm  /
```

How can I resize the partition under `sda3` to make use of the entire drive?

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958114/resize-ubuntu-dev-sda1-partition-in-virtualbox-vmdk-when-dev-sda-is-already-la), but it is quite a bit more complex than what I am working with, and I'm not quite sure what to google to get to the root of my issue.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Why did you make `/boot` on a separate 1G partition?

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm not sure why `/boot` has a 1G partition. It must have happened when I was installing somehow. But yes, I believe this link will help. Thank you!

Comment: @Pilot6 I've tried to resize the partitions following the link, but in GParted it says the full ~500GB is partitioned for sda3. I cannot expand the partition any larger than it already is, and I cannot change the size of the `ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` section

Comment: You can shrink `/boot` first.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be interesing to see more logs but OOTB I wonder if you inadvertently setup a RAID[1] configuration.

A quick way to check is to run : `sudo mdadm /dev/sda`

or alternativelty check if these files exist and their contents:

- `cat /proc/mdstat`
- `cat /etc/mdadm.conf`

If this is indeed the case I suggest the fastest way in a new system is to simply reinstall making sure no RAID configuration is used. I believe it is possible to remove a RAID config on a live system but I'm not familiar enough with it and wouldn't risk it myself. A backup and reinstall might be the fastest path.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID

Comment: `sudo mdadm /dev/sda` shows `/dev/sda: is not an md array`. `cat /proc/mdstat` shows this output: https://pastebin.com/L4QeKL15. `cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` shows this output: https://pastebin.com/SJksPf9W. I don't believe I have a RAID array set up based on the first command, but I could be wrong in what I see

Comment: I can get any other logs you'd like to see, as well, if you're interested